# Why does Spark not take full advantage of parallel resources for a long time?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was running a sparksql application in spark-shell. The screen progress bar logs like below:

```
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1722 + 20) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1725 + 20) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1726 + 20) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1728 + 19) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1730 + 17) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1737 + 15) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1738 + 14) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1742 + 12) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1746 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1749 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1750 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1752 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1755 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1759 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1763 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1766 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1770 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1774 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1775 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1776 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1781 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1785 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1787 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1790 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                        (1792 + 10) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                         (1793 + 9) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                         (1794 + 8) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                         (1795 + 7) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                         (1797 + 5) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                         (1798 + 4) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                         (1800 + 2) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                         (1801 + 1) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                       (1801 + 100) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                       (1802 + 100) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                       (1805 + 100) / 8040]
[Stage 3:===========>                                       (1810 + 100) / 8040]
```

In this stage, sparksql was reading data from a hive table.

Although the parallel resources was sufficient (10 executor, each has 10 cores), spark did not let enough tasks to execute. Only 10 or less tasks was being executed concurrently for serveral minutes. Until the last "ONE" task (1801 + 1) finished, spark then start to put more tasks into execute queue (IN THE SAME STAGE).

Why this happened repeatly and how to make spark take full advantage of the parallel resources?

My environment is:

```
Hadoop-2.7.7
Hive-2.3.6
Spark-2.4.4 ~ Spark-3.0.0
```

Comment: What's the data format of your hive table? Is the hive table is partitioned? What kind of aggregation you are performing?

Comment: resource manager was?

Comment: what do you mean by repeatedly?

Comment: Hive table is stored as orc and partitioned, aggregation is joining with another small table then count(1), but I think this stage is reading data (because I was reading 2 partitions which shows 8040 tasks in progress bar, if I read the whole table, the total tasks would be 53000 in this stage) not doing aggregation. Resource manager is yarn with fair scheduler. This phenomenon happens **repeatedly** every time I run this sql.

Comment: OK, thanks. fair scheduler allocating resources in a noisy cluster?

Comment: Not very noisy, about 3~5 sparksql application running at sametime

Comment: Interesting for sure. Let us know if you resolve it. Can you run it on its own to check? hard to assess at a distance.

Comment: did you try running on its own?

Comment: You mean running on local master?